# Intel(r) Visual Fortran run-time error while running ANSYS Mechanical

Tags: fortran, intel

I'm running some simulations in Matlab (solving an inverse problem) on a remote computer running on windows 7 and I'm using a loop in which I call for Ansys Mechanical to do some calculation before using the results.
It was running fine but after several iterations (87) I received an error coming from Ansys Mechanical [See the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge6S2.png)

Closing this window close Ansys Mechanical and after reopening it, I have the following Ansys Mechanical APDL Launcher Error: "Cannot create required '//mypath/../AppData/Ansys/v150/launcher/profiles.lock' file. Therefore, cannot write to profile information during this launcher session" By clicking on OK on other window open saying "The launcher menu option 'Write Laucnher Log File' is selected. However, because you currently only have read access to the launcher profile, you will also not be permitted to write to the launcher log file during this launcher session".

After that, I can sometimes restart my simulation after a while (which will stop after a certain number of iterations) but if I want to start it again just after having seen the error, I get the Fortran error during the first iteration.

I don't know much about Fortran and I haven't seen any similar post. Have any of you already had this issue ?

Thanks for the help,

Nathan

Comment: From https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/300605 it looks like this is not really a fortran error but a problem with the windows system which causes the fortran program to fail. For a wild guess can you check that you have not run out of disk space/exceeded your quota.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error, I mean does it stop always aftter 87th iteration? Can you run this on your local filesystem? I guess this would solve your problem for sure.

Comment: The error doesn't always happen after the 87th iteration, it's quite random. I'm trying to run it on my local filesystem (I just started it and it will take 4 days to run). Thanks a lot for the link d_1999.

Comment: It solved it, thanks a lot !